# is this a nested if? and while loop? not sure if I'm using them right. but I'm getting errors. "else without if"

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, nested

//decides if user will get commission on top of pay.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class commiPay{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pay = 200;
        double com;
        double sales;
        double x;
        while ( sales = -1 )// I want the user to enter positive numbers
        {
            System.out.printf( "Sales cannot be negative");
            System.out.printf( "Enter sales sold this week: ");
        }
        System.out.println("Enter sales made this week: ");
        sales = input.nextInt(); 
        if ( sales >= 7500 )/*got this format from the traditional letter grade java example**/
        {
            System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 5%. " );
            com = sales*.5;
         else if ( sales >= 5001 )
             System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 4%. " );
             com = sales*.4;
         else if ( sales >= 2501 )
             System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 3%. " );
            com = sales*.3;   
         else if ( sales >= 1001 )
             System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 2%. " );
             com = sales*.2;    
         else ( sales < 1000 )
             System.out.println( "No commission. " );
             total = pay;
         }
         System.out.println( "You will get paid" + total + "this week."  );
     }
}
```

A salesperson is paid **$200.00 a week** plus **a commission**. The commission depends on the amount of sales she(he) has made during the week.

Write a program that will prompt the user for the amount of sales for a week ( use an integer for the amount of sales ).

If the amount entered is less than 0, display an error message that tells the user "The sales amount cannot be negative!"

Using the information in the table below, determine what the salesperson's commission should be.  The commission should be based on the total sales for the week.

Commission Table:

```
        up to 1,000                              no commission
        1,001 – 2,500                            2% of sales
        2,501 – 5,000                            3% of sales
        5,001 – 7,500                            4% of sales
        over 7,500                               5% of sales
```

Comment: Look at your braces.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you format the if/elseif/else statements correctly:

```
if() {

} else if() {

} else if() {

} else {

}
```

Comment: While this is probably the right answer, please also explain where the OP went wrong in his formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a lot of brackets in your code. You will also need to initialize your variables. Type in a value of less 1000 and you will see that the code now works. There was also some of your code that was not implemented yet that I fixed.  Within each if or else if block you needed to add the `com` and `pay` variables to your `total` variable. I also noticed that your decimal points were off in your commission formulas.

For example:

You had this in your code  `com = sales * .2;`, This would yield a 20% percent commission instead of the 2% in your code comments. The correct formula is:

```
com = sales * 0.02;
```

I applied this fix through out your code.

```
    /decides if user will get commission on top of pay.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class commiPay {

public static void main( String[] args )

{ 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);




  double pay = 200;

  //added this variable(was missing from your code)
  double total = 0;

  double com = 0;//

  //intialize sales variable
  double sales = 0;

  double x;


  //The following to lines were moved to before the while loop
  System.out.println("Enter sales made this week: ");

     sales = input.nextInt();


  //while the sales number is positive
 while ( sales < 0 )// I want the user to enter positive numbers
  {
     System.out.printf( "Sales cannot be negative");


     System.out.println("Enter sales made this week: ");

         sales = input.nextInt();
  }









  if ( sales >= 7500 )/*got this format from the traditional letter grade java example**/
   {
     System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 5%. " );

       com = sales * 0.05;

     //add the commission to the total
       total = pay + com;

   }





 else if ( sales >= 5001 ){//added bracket

     System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 4%. " );
     com = sales * 0.04;

     //add the commission to the total
     total = pay + com;

 }//added bracket//added bracket//added bracket//added bracket
  else if ( sales >= 2501 ){//added bracket


     System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 3%. " );

      com = sales * 0.03;

    //add the commission to the total
       total = pay + com;

  }//added bracket//added bracket//added bracket//added bracket
  else if ( sales >= 1001 ){//added brace

      System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 2%. " );

       com = sales * 0.02;

       //add the commission to the total
       total = pay + com;


  }//added bracket//added bracket//added bracket//added bracket
  else if( sales < 1000 ){


     System.out.println( "No commission. " );
             total = pay;

   }




  System.out.println( "You will get paid " + (total) + " this week."  );





   }//end main method

}//end class
```

Comment: OP wants to check whether the number is positive or not but in your code its checking whether the number is equals to -1 or not.

Comment: Good point,I was just fixing the syntax error from there original code.

Comment: But this time your while loop creates an infinite loop. Look at my answer.

Comment: Looks like still there are some errors. Your while loop is always false. It is not checking the user input.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have more than one line after your else if, you need to place it inside of braces in order to make sure your program doesn't get confused. As I know it, you can only use

```
else if(something)
     indented something;
else if(something else)
etc.
```

if you only have one line.

```
else if ( sales >= 5001 )
             System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 4%. " );
             com = sales*.4;
```

needs to be

```
else if ( sales >= 5001 ){
             System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 4%. " );
             com = sales*.4;
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing brackets and in your `while condition` and calculations are also wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class commiPay{
public static void main( String[] args ){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pay = 200;
    double com;
    double sales = 0;
    double x;
    double total; // added this variable

    //First you need to get the user input. So I added these two lines to here.
    System.out.println("Enter sales made this week: ");
    sales = input.nextInt();

    //Checking whether enterd number is a positive or not
    while ( sales < 0 )// I want the user to enter positive numbers
    {
        System.out.printf( "Sales cannot be negative ");
        System.out.printf( "Enter sales sold this week: ");
        sales = input.nextInt(); // if the entered number is an negative number ask the user to re enter the number 
    }

    if ( sales >= 7500 )/*got this format from the traditional letter grade java example**/
    {
        System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 5%. " );
        com = sales*0.05;
    }
     else if ( sales >= 5001 ){
         System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 4%. " );
         com = sales*0.04;
     }
     else if ( sales >= 2501 ){
         System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 3%. " );
        com = sales*0.03;
     }
     else if ( sales >= 1001 ){
         System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 2%. " );
         com = sales*0.02;
     }
     else if( sales < 1000 ){
         System.out.println( "No commission. " );
         total = pay;
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Your sales = input.nextInt();  code in your while loop will never be reached. Once the user enters a negative number the program ends.

Comment: Never mind I see that you moved call to get the user input before the while loop.

Comment: Yes. Because we are using the while loop only to check the user input so we need to get the user input before checking it.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following:

```
    while ( sales = -1)
```

But what if they don't enter -1 specifically? It should be:

```
    while ( sales < 0 )
```

This will cover any negative numbers. You should also revise your brackets as you appear to be missing a few. You could also do without the **printf** after your **while** loop and use a standard **println**:

```
    while ( sales = -1 )// I want the user to enter positive numbers
    {
        System.out.printf( "Sales cannot be negative");
        System.out.printf( "Enter sales sold this week: ");
```

But I don't think it will cause a problem.

As for the rest of your code, you sstate in your printed lines that the sales will be multiplied by 5%, but multiply them by 0.5 (as follows):

```
    System.out.println( "Commission is multiplied by 5%. " );
        com = sales*.5;
```

Multiplying by 0.5 would make it 50%. Try swapping it to 0.05 (5/100).